# update database rows using foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, database, loops, foreach

I have a table in my database is called "books_term",

when I submit a book, book and its categories store in this table.
some of my books have multiple categories, so I decided to store each category as a new row + book_id

for example :

```
id             category_id            book_id
 1                   23                 14
 2                   45                 14
 3                   30                 14
```

this is "books_term" table structure, as you can see, book number 14 has three categories (23,45,30)

everything works fine until I decided to update the book in the admin panel of my cms.

the question is: how can I update this books category?
and how can I update book categories if the book exists in "books_term" otherwise insert?
should I use `foreach` loop for this purpose?

this is my php code and it does not work correctly,

```
   $values = $_POST['category'];
   $myid = $_POST['bookid'];
   foreach($values as $value) {
     $check = "SELECT * FROM books_term WHERE book_id = '$myid'";
     $checkresult = mysqli_query($connection,$check);
     if(mysqli_num_rows($checkresult) > 0){
        $update_query = "UPDATE books_term SET category_id = '$value' WHERE book_id = '$myid'";
        mysqli_query($connection,$update_query);
        echo 'updated';
     }else{
        $insert_query = "INSERT INTO books_term (category_id,book_id) VALUES ('$value','$myid')";
        mysqli_query($connection,$insert_query);
        echo 'inserted';
    }
}
```

in the edit page, when I select multiple categories and click on the update button, it just set last selected category to book_id 14,  like in the picture below:

[image]

Comment: What doesn't work correctly? Is there an error? Are you checking for errors?

Comment: @kchason in edit page, when i select multiple categories for my book and click update post, this query sets last selected category value (for example : category 9)  to book number 14

Comment: @kchason take a look at above picture.

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: @tadman thanks for the advice <3  but it is personal coding, and i'm testing it in this method , for future production i will consider your advices

Comment: If you're learning, learn the correct way of doing things. This is extremely important to get right as even tiny, innocent mistakes can cost you huge. You want to be an asset to any team you work on, not a liability. Doing it correctly is not hard, not time consuming and *will* save you considerable time.

Comment: @tadman how can i do this thing using the correct way ?

Comment: @tadman can you make and example for me ?

Comment: I've put a number of links in the original comment that should set you on the right path. There's also [PHP the Right Way](https://www.phptherightway.com) for general advice. Simply `mysqli_query($conn, $query)` becomes `$conn->query($query)` and so on, much less verbose, way fewer chances of screwing it up by accident.

Comment: @tadman in this specific problem i want to know how to solve my problem using the right way... if you can make an example for this problem i'll appreciate that <3

Comment: If you prepare a single statement you can use the same statement repeatedly in a loop. This is much faster than running `query` a whole bunch of times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can just delete the data first and insert it again

```
$values = $_POST['category'];
$myid = $_POST['bookid']; 
$delete_query = "DELETE FROM books_terms WHERE book_id='$myid'";
mysqli_query($connection,$delete_query);
foreach($values as $value) {
    $insert_query = "INSERT INTO books_term (category_id,book_id) VALUES ('$value','$myid')";
    mysqli_query($connection,$insert_query);
    echo 'inserted';
}
```

Comment: thanks mate .  it's working...
but as @kchason said yesterday, i'm now using pdo for connecting to database and queries....

but i'd tested your code and it works